# Solving multiplication of complex numbers : $(\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt{2})^{3}*(-\sqrt{3}+i)^{2}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Please take a look at my solution for below multiplication and correct me if it's wrong:

$(\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt{2})^{3}*(-\sqrt{3}+i)^{2}$

I start with $(\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt{2})^{3}$ :

$r=\sqrt{2+2}=2$

$\tan(\theta)=\dfrac{-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}=-1 => \theta=\dfrac{7\pi}{4}$

$=[2cis\dfrac{7\pi}{4}]^{3}=8cis\dfrac{5\pi}{4}$

also in $(-\sqrt{3}+i)^{2}$  :

$r=\sqrt{3+1}=2$

$\tan(\theta)=\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{3}} => \theta=\dfrac{5\pi}{6}$

$=[2cis\dfrac{5\pi}{6}]^{2}=4cis\dfrac{5\pi}{3}$

now when I get back to main problem it comes as :

$8cis\dfrac{5\pi}{4}*4cis\dfrac{5\pi}{3}=32cis(\dfrac{5\pi}{4}+\dfrac{5\pi}{3})$

Comment: I think the title should say " ... multiplication of complex numbers ... "

Comment: @ArnieDris you can edit title to what you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT (find your mistake):

$$\left(\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt{2}\right)^3\cdot\left(-\sqrt{3}+i\right)^2=$$
$$\left(\left|\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt{2}\right|e^{\arg\left(\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt{2}\right)i}\right)^3\cdot\left(\left|-\sqrt{3}+i\right|e^{\arg\left(-\sqrt{3}+i\right)i}\right)^2=$$
$$\left(2e^{-\arctan\left(\frac{1}{1}\right)i}\right)^3\cdot\left(\sqrt{4}e^{\frac{5\pi}{6}i}\right)^2=$$
$$\left(2e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}i}\right)^3\cdot\left(2e^{\frac{5\pi}{6}i}\right)^2=$$
$$\left(8e^{-\frac{3\pi}{4}i}\right)\cdot\left(4e^{\frac{5\pi}{3}i}\right)=$$
$$32e^{\frac{11\pi}{12}i}$$

Comment: thank you for your answer.$\dfrac{5\pi}{4}=-\dfrac{3\pi}{4}$ which means my solution has no mistake!

Comment: You're welcome! Yes indeed